# How to make an Okhttp Request with "Content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded"?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, okhttp

I have an api requirement of Sending following parameters in header-

Content-Type - application/x-www-form-urlencoded

authKey- (Session token)

and following parameters in body(form day i.e key-value pair)

storeId -1

type -Product

CategoryId -324

But whenever I hit this api, I am always getting 401(UnAuthorized) error.
I have tried using MultipartRequest body and formBody, I know this is nothing to do with the body(Its the header where I need to send the Content-Type and authKey). Below is my code-

```
Request.Builder  requestBuilder = new Request.Builder();
requestBuilder.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    requestBuilder.addHeader("authKey",AppSharedPref.getTokenMobikul(context));
RequestBody formbody = new FormBody.Builder().add("CategoryId",bodyparms.get(0)).
                        add("type",bodyparms.get(1)).build();
 requestBuilder.post(formbody);
```

The Same api is giving Response with retrofit library So how to achieve this using Okhttp.

Answer (score 3):

Might this will help

```
FormBody.Builder formBuilder = new FormBody.Builder()
    .add("key", "value");

// add more parameter as follow:
formBuilder.add("mobile", "9999999999");

RequestBody formBody = formBuilder.build();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("https://www.hittheserver.com")
            .post(formBody)
            .build();
```