# React-native-uploader Android Errors

Tags: java, android, react-native

I'm currently trying to debug a react-native package ([react-native-uploader](https://github.com/tranquangvu/react-native-uploader)) I'm using to try and upload a bundle of files (photos). Despite working on ios, the current implementation is returning the following error for android:

```
Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=405, message=Method Not Allowed, url=${config.apiBase}/load/${this.props.id}/uploadconfirmation}
```

The error is originating from this line in the package:

`Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();`

Where the client is:

`private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient()`

Where request is:

```
Request{method=POST, url=${config.apiBase}/load/${this.props.id}/uploadconfirmation, tag=null}
```

I've successfully made posts to the endpoint using formdata:

```
    let tData = new FormData();
    const that = this;

    tData.append("confirmation_doc", {
      uri: files[0].filepath,
      type: "image/jpeg",
      name: "confirmation_doc.jpg",
    });    

    axios.post(
      `${config.apiBase}/load/${this.props.id}/uploadconfirmation`,
           tData
    )
    .then(response => {
        Alert.alert(
          "Success",
          "Uploaded Successfully!",
          [{ text: "OK", onPress: () => that.props.close() }],
          { cancelable: false }
        );
    });
```

I've tried looking through the [source code](https://github.com/tranquangvu/react-native-uploader/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/burlap/filetransfer/FileTransferModule.java) to determine where things are falling apart and it seems like everything is posting as it should (headers look good, method looks good, endpoint looks good). I'm not all too familiar with Java so any input would be appreciated.

Comment: are you sure that the given implmentation is working fine on iOS?

Comment: Yes, given the same parameters:

`RNUploader.upload(opts, (err, response) => {});`

where opts is 

`let opts = {
      url: ${config.apiBase}/load/${this.props.id}/uploadconfirmation,
      files,
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        Authorization: Bearer ${this.props.user.token},
      }, 
    };`

the react-native app uploads files correctly on ios

Comment: @ArielSalem that `Accept` header is certainly wrong (because it is a server-side header); it should probably be `ContentType` instead; with value `multipart/form-data` (which might be set by `new FormData()` and the later `Accept` is not being taken into account).

Comment: @MartinZeitler, thanks for the heads up. I'll give that a shot and see if it works

Comment: @MartinZeitler, thanks for the heads up. I should mention that the repo is defaulting (https://github.com/tranquangvu/react-native-uploader/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/burlap/filetransfer/FileTransferModule.java#L133) the Accept Headers. The good news is to switching out the Accept Headers for ContentType returned a bad request error:

`Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=400, message=Bad Request`

The bad news is, I've got no idea why changing the ContentType would've changed it. I'm going to take a look at the link you posted below and see if I can glean any info about the issue.

Comment: @ArielSalem guess the server might only accept `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` ... leaving that `Accept` header away should make no difference. I might be wrong, while I still think this header is server-side (because I can hardly think of a situation, where a client would have to accept). `multipart/form-data` would be the best content type for image upload, but only while the server accepts it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51259058/how-to-make-an-okhttp-request-with-content-typeapplication-x-www-form-urlencod this might be the other option.

Comment: @MartinZeitler, just seeing this comment. I think you bring up a great point. it looks like the repo is setting a default to the `Accept` headers, which is resetting the value rather than appending an additional value. If that's the case then that could be where the issue arises. I'll change the headers to `addHeaders` and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @MartinZeitler, while the link you've sent through does seem to deal with similar circumstances (i.e. adding form data to be sent through the a request body), the solution proposed doesn't seem to be fitting, since the existing repo already seems to be performing a similar bit of functionality: (https://github.com/tranquangvu/react-native-uploader/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/burlap/filetransfer/FileTransferModule.java#L117)

Comment: @MartinZeitler, strangely enough after tweaking the source code to addHeader (to account for the other header type) the upload call is timing out. I'll do some local testing to see what's going on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve this issue, I had to abandon the `react-native-uploader` package I had been using. Below is how I managed to resolve the issue:

```
let tData = new FormData();

this.state.selectedImages.forEach((item, i) => {
  tData.append("doc[]", {
    uri: item.uri,
    type: "image/jpeg",
    name: item.filename || `filename${i}.jpg`,
  });
});

fetch(`${config.apiBase}/load/${this.props.id}/uploadconfirmation`, {
  method: "post",
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    Authorization: `Token ${this.props.token}`,
  },
  body: tData,
})
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => {
    Alert.alert(
      "Success",
      "Uploaded Successfully!",
      [{ text: "OK", onPress: () => that.props.close() }],
      { cancelable: false }
    );
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error("error uploading images: ", err);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

HTTP [405](https://httpstatuses.com/405) Method Not Allowed ... is a client-side error.

> The method received in the request-line is known by the origin server but not supported by the target resource.

if the `JavaScript` works, but the `Java` won't... you might be looking for the [MultipartBuilder](https://square.github.io/okhttp/2.x/okhttp/com/squareup/okhttp/MultipartBuilder.html)

... in combination with `MediaType.FORM`.

Comment: Hey @MartinZeitler, I've been playing around with the MediaType and it doesn't seem like that's the issue here since it's still returning the same error. Thanks for the heads up though!

Comment: @ArielSalem it all depends what the server would expect, for posting an image without a form, it would be eg. `MediaType.parse("image/png")`. see the recipes: https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes

Comment: Right, which is what it's default behavior is. Since we're posting `image/jpg` files and using `MediaType.parse(mimetype)` [https://github.com/tranquangvu/react-native-uploader/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/burlap/filetransfer/FileTransferModule.java#L109]

where `mimetype = 'image/jpg'` it doesn't seem like MediaType is the issue here.

Comment: So basically, the server is expecting an image/png, which would mean that the existing functionality should be able to parse through the information relevantly since we aren't submitting a form. Unfortunately the maintainer of the repo isn't active / responsive so I'm going to keep messing around until I find a solution. Thanks for your help @MartinZeitler